# Benefit of using Dependency Injection inside ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I am reading this article about using DI inside ASP.NET Core @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0 .. but i can not understand its benefit of providing abstraction level.

for example without DI, we will have those classes:-

```
public class MyDependency
{
    public void WriteMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"MyDependency.WriteMessage called. Message: {message}");
    }
}

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MyDependency _dependency = new MyDependency();

    public void OnGet()
    {
        _dependency.WriteMessage("IndexModel.OnGet");
    }
}
```

and with DI we will have those classes:-

```
public interface IMyDependency
{
    void WriteMessage(string message);
}
public class MyDependency : IMyDependency
{
    public void WriteMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"MyDependency.WriteMessage Message: {message}");
    }
}
public class Index2Model : PageModel
{
    private readonly IMyDependency _myDependency;

    public Index2Model(IMyDependency myDependency)
    {
        _myDependency = myDependency;            
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        _myDependency.WriteMessage("Index2Model.OnGet");
    }
}
```

but at the end with DI or without DI if i want to modify the WriteMessage method, to accept 2 strings instead of one as follow:-

```
public void WriteMessage(string message,string message2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"MyDependency.WriteMessage called. Message: {message}{message2}");
        }
```

i will have to modify the related classes; without DI case:-

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MyDependency _dependency = new MyDependency();

    public void OnGet()
    {
        _dependency.WriteMessage("IndexModel.OnGet","two");
    }
}
```

with DI case:-

```
public class Index2Model : PageModel
{
    private readonly IMyDependency _myDependency;

    public Index2Model(IMyDependency myDependency)
    {
        _myDependency = myDependency;            
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        _myDependency.WriteMessage("Index2Model.OnGet","two");
    }
}
```

so not sure how using DI will create an abstraction between the `WriteMessage` implementation and the classes which consume it.. or i am understanding DI and its benefits wrongly?

Thanks

Comment: Think about it from the perspective of where the message is written, it could be written to the console, to a file, to a SQL database, to a message queue, to an email, etc... all of these would require a different version of the dependency 'writer' depending on their output destination. If you 'new' up an instance in your IndexModel class then you have tightly coupled that particular dependency writer to your IndexModel (and everywhere else you use `new` to create an instance). On the other hand, if you pass it in as a dependency then you only have coupled it at the 'top' of your application.

Comment: DI will not protect a methods signature from change, that's not what it's for. If you want to protect a method signature from changing you could create an object to contain the parameters and then pass that as your parameter. If you need to add additional properties you would update the parameter object and not the method signature.

Comment: @quaabaam then what is the benefits of using DI? i can not see any based on the example i showed which is taken from MS documentation

Comment: DI does not provide the benefits you are looking for. If you create another class implementing interface `IMyDependency` all you need to do is change the DI map with that class and all the consumers of `IMyDependency` will start using that class. You don't need to go every where in the code and change to the new class. Also if you unit test the Index2Model class, you don't need to worry about how exactly `_myDependency.WriteMessage` method will behave. You can control that by using mocks.

Comment: Imagine your dependency connects to the database or file system. And at the time of unit test the database or file system is not available. The unit tests will fail due to dependencies which are not even required for testing `Idex2Model` code. These are some of the benefits you get using DI.

Comment: Stack Overflow's information on the [dependency-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dependency-injection/info) tag actually contains a wealth of information and links to Stack Overflow answers on DI and other resources such as books. My advice would be: read one of the books. For instance, there's a freely available [chapter one](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-1) of my book that you can read online. This gives an introduction of the benefits of DI.

Comment: @Chetan actually the benefits of using DI which i were proposing is described in MS link `To replace MyDependency with a different implementation, the IndexModel class must be modified.`

Comment: @johnGu `To replace MyDependency with a different implementation, the IndexModel class must be modified.` is not the benefit of DI. It is the issue you face when not using DI. If you want to replace the `MyDependency` with different implementation without modifying `IndexModel` class, you should use DI.

Comment: DI has more benefits than just "replacing dependency with different implementation", and they are listed in your article. Imagine `MyDependency` itself depends on a logger to write that message too, so it accepts some `Logger` in constructor. ``Logger` in turn accepts path to the file it should log to. Now you cannot even create `MyDependency` inside `Index2Model` like in your example without DI, because `Index2Model` has no idea to which file that logger should write to, no should it care of course.

Comment: Actually that link by @Steven in comments contains a pretty good overview and it's more than enough to understand the concept, certainly more than we can fit in an answer here

Answer (score 5):

I want to point out that you don't have to use interfaces to use dependency injection. You definitely can, and that's great if you want to enforce a contract where you may potentially have a different implementation in the future. But it's not required. You can inject a service or other dependency without an interface.

One of the key benefits to DI is that you don't have to wire up the dependencies manually. In the example you gave `MyDependency` doesn't have any dependencies. But what if it had four arguments for other services, or repositories etc. Now in `Index2Model` you have to create an instance of all of those dependencies, pass them into your new `MyDependency` constructor. It becomes a lot of work if you have a more complex application. With DI it just gives you an instance all ready to go.

The other big one is scopes. One big issue that I've seen in many different software products is accidental state. Someone gets a bit sloppy with their coding and creates a variable in a class and if that same instance gets used by more than one request you can have accidental state in the application.

With DI you can default to a transient dependency where each time you go to use the dependency it's a brand new instance, but you can easily switch a particular dependency to be scoped which keeps the same instance for the lifecycle of an HTTP request, which would be difficult to replicate manually, or you could set it to singleton when that makes sense.

Comment: The best answer so far and the only answer which doesn't mix DI with the IoC.

Comment: @Artur I've found that many people don't realize that the two things are separate concepts. DI makes IoC easier to do and both are implemented in the .net core templates so people don't understand the relationship between the two concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Roughly, It reduces dependency and makes code more reusable.

Imagine you have an implementation of `IMyDependency` and you would like to change it to another one, you just need to change the DI configuration instead of change all `MyDependency` references in your code.

You can also make use of patterns in a simpler way (e.g. singleton/transient instances).

You make code more testeable, mocking interfaces and making use of constructor injection.

Check more advantages in https://jenkov.com/tutorials/dependency-injection/dependency-injection-benefits.html

Comment: not sure i got your point, i posted 2 examples one using DI and the other using non-DI .. seems to me they are the same...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is almost impossible to look at DI as a standalone concept to understand its benefit, you will need to at least understand the difference between a normal class and a class that implements the interface.

Secondly, you are looking at the benefit of DI in the wrong aspects as per @quaabaam's comment.

Without the prerequisites, I hope the below can give you an idea of one of the benefits of using DI.

Based on your example, imagine your dependency class `MyDependency` is used in more than one place/class. Later on, when you need to replace it with `MyUpdatedDependency1`(which is very likely nowadays), you will need to update everywhere that used `MyDependency`.

A solution to the above would create an interface class `IDependency`, and create implementation class like `MyDependency` and `MyUpdatedDependency1`.  And allow DI to manage the initialization for you.

As a result, With DI, all you need to do is update your initial set-up `AddScope<IDependency,MyDependency>` to `AddScope<IDependency,MyUpdatedDependency1>`

Then DI will handle the rest for you, which includes **initialize** the **target** implementation class everywhere.

Comment: @wjxiew actually the benefits of using DI which i were proposing is described in MS link `To replace MyDependency with a different implementation, the IndexModel class must be modified.
`

Answer (score 0):

In short the benefits are simple; Provide decoupling from implementation details, improve reusability, provide really good testing benefits as well. Without Injection doing a unit test for your app is more than trivial as you need to understand the inner workings of the dependency implementation. Rather with injection you can mock, stub, or fake out the dependencies methods. Or.. in C# case use profiler tools like Microsoft Fakes to allow you to change the dependency behavior which is less than ideal if you have ever used said tools. Using dependency Injection also goes a long way for using the Dependency Inversion principle, sense its built off not having your classes directly depend on lower level implementations same level abstractions ( interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with simple demo code like the linked example is that the true benefits of DI / Abstractions / IoC are only realised when the situation is more complicated.

In reality your code would look more like:

```
public class MyDependency
{
    public void WriteMessage(string message)
    {
        // Write to some external email / SMS / database
        // Requires credentials / network access
        // Might cost money or trigger rate limits
    }
}

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MyDependency _dependency = new MyDependency();

    public void OnGet()
    {
        if (oneThing || another)
        {            
             var message = GetMessageViaSomeTwistedLogic();
            _dependency.WriteMessage(message);
        }
        else
        {
            _dependency.WriteMessage("Something totally different");
        }
    }
}
```

So when you come to write tests for your `IndexModel` class then using an interface or an abstract class allows you to test *all* of the logic in the class *without* spamming lots of emails or having database access from your build server or running up a huge bill sending SMSs

There are many other useful features, in particular

- scopes
- constructor changes
- sub dependency changes

but for me testing is the feature that is least mentioned but most important

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection is the design pattern that helps us to create an application which loosely coupled. This means that objects should only have those dependencies that are required to complete tasks. The main advantage of DI (Dependency Injection) is our application is loosely coupled and has provided greater maintainability, testability, and also re-usability. It is loosely coupled because dependency required by the class is injected from the outer world rather than created themselves directly win-in code.

There are three types of DI: Construction Injection, Setter Injection, Interface based Injection. The Construction Injection type of DI accepts their dependency at the constructor level which means that when creating an object of the class, their dependency passes through the constructor of the class. It provides a strong dependency contract between objects. The Setter Injection is also known as property injection. In this type of dependency injection, dependency passes through public property instead of the constructor. It allows us to pass the dependencies when required. It does not provide a strong dependency contract between objects. The interface-based dependency injection can be achieved by creating the common interface and other classes are implements this interface to inject the dependency. In this type of DI, we can use either constructor injection or setter injection.

There is a built-in support of dependency injection in ASP.net Core. This supports is not limited to middleware, but also support in Controllers, views, and model as well. There are two types of service containers provided by the ASP.net core: Framework Services and Application Services. The framework services are service that is provided by the ASP.net core such as ILoggerFactory etc. The application services are the custom services created based on our requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It could be explained very simple let's consider that you have a class (i.e. **`class A`**) that is instantiated with quite **big number of arguments** (**10 or 11** and some of them are also classes with complicated arguments)

- Let's suppose hat you use them in many parts of you app, aggregate them in classes
  `F`, `G` and others. If you should change a number of arguments of class A you
  have to change in every place where you use it. Using DI you have to change it in
  **single place**. So using `DI` you just **simplify you work**.
- Sometimes you have to manage lifetime of you services (free resources after
  operation is completed (i.e. `per request`), or keep some resources (`singleton`)
  as long as app is running. Using `DI` **you could forget about objects lifetime
  management by hands**.